# Improve Performance .net core 2.1 web api

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, angular7, asp.net-core-2.1

I have created real estate website, my backend is .net core 2.1 and  frontend is angular 7. For DB I am using sql server, now i have 1568 data (buildings information) in my database. I have performance issue in my backend, when i search data  from db it takes more than 30 sec to show data.  I  readed many information about indexing in sql server and i created non clustered index in my db but when I tested in sql server , it doesn't use index which i created. How  I can  improve performance of my backend here is my search code:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Search([FromBody] SearchModel model)
        {    try
            { var query = _service.AllAsQueryable;

                if (model != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Keyword))
                    { 


                        var keyword = model.Keyword.ToLower();
                        query = query.Where(a => a.BuildTitle.ToLower().Contains(keyword) ||
                                                 a.Description.ToLower().Contains(keyword) ||
                                                 a.ZipCode.ToLower().Contains(keyword) ||
                                                // (a.Country != null && a.Country.Localizations.Any(b => b.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword))) ||
                                                 (a.Region != null && a.Region.Localizations.Any(b => b.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword))) ||
                                                 (a.District != null && a.District.Localizations.Any(b => b.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword))) ||
                                                 (a.Zone != null && a.Zone.Localizations.Any(b => b.Name.ToLower().Contains(keyword))));


                    }

                    if (model.RegionId.HasValue && model.RegionId > 0)
                        query = query.Where(a => a.RegionId == model.RegionId);

                    if (model.DistrictId.HasValue && model.DistrictId > 0)
                        query = query.Where(a => a.DistrictId == model.DistrictId);

                    if (model.ZoneId.HasValue && model.ZoneId > 0)
                        query = query.Where(a => a.ZoneId == model.ZoneId);

                    if (model.ClientTypeId.HasValue && model.ClientTypeId > 0)
                        query = query.Where(a => a.ClientTypeId == model.ClientTypeId);

                    if (model.PriceFrom.HasValue)
                        query = query.Where(a => a.OwnerPrice >= model.PriceFrom);

                    if (model.PriceTo.HasValue && model.PriceTo > 0)
                        query = query.Where(a => a.OwnerPrice <= model.PriceTo);

                    if (model.Size != null && model.Size.SizeNameId > 0)
                    {
                        query = query.Where(a => a.SizeNameId == model.Size.SizeNameId);

                        if (model.Size.SizeFrom.HasValue)
                            query = query.Where(a => a.SizeNameId == model.Size.SizeNameId && a.Size >= model.Size.SizeFrom && a.Size <= model.Size.SizeTo);
                    }

                    if (model.BuildActionTypes?.Length > 0)
                        query = query.Where(a => a.BuildAction != null && model.BuildActionTypes.Contains(a.BuildAction.Id));

                    if (model.BuildTypes?.Length > 0)
                        query = query.Where(a => a.BuildType != null && model.BuildTypes.Contains(a.BuildType.Id));

                    if (model.Rooms?.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var room in model.Rooms)
                        {
                            query = query.Where(a => a.BuildingRooms.Any(b => b.RoomType == room.Type && room.Count.Contains(b.RoomCount)));
                        }
                    }

                    switch (model.SortType)
                    {
                        case SortType.Asc:
                            query = query.OrderBy(a => a.OwnerPrice);
                            break;
                        case SortType.Desc:
                            query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.OwnerPrice);
                            break;
                        case SortType.Newest:
                            query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate);
                            break;
                    }

                    if (model.Points != null)
                    {
                        query = query.Where(a => a.Latitude.HasValue && a.Latitude >= model.Points.X1 && a.Latitude <= model.Points.X2 &&
                                                 a.Longitude.HasValue && a.Longitude >= model.Points.Y1 && a.Longitude <= model.Points.Y2);
                    }
                }
                var totalCount = query.Count();
                var result = query.Skip(model.PageSize * (model.CurrentPage - 1))
                                  .Take(model.PageSize)
                                  .AsEnumerable()
                                  .Select(a =>
                                  {
                                      var building = a.MapTo<BuildingShortDetailsViewModel>();
                                      building.LoadEntity(a);
                                      return building;
                                  });
                var searchResult = new SearchResult
                {
                    Filter = model,
                    Locations = query.Select(a => new LocationModel
                    {
                        BuildingId = a.Id,
                        Latitude = a.Latitude.ToString(),
                        Longitude = a.Longitude.ToString(),
                        OwnerPrice= a.OwnerPrice,
                        Size= a.Size,
                        SizeName= a.SizeName.Id,
                        BuildingPhotos= a.BuildingPhotos,
                        BuildAction=a.BuildAction.Id,
                    }),
                    Buildings = result,
                    TotalCount = totalCount
                };

                return Ok(searchResult);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest($"Error occured while getting search result. Error: {ex.Message}. StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, avoid

```
var totalCount = query.Count();
```

That runs the query just to count the rows.  Just tell your UI whether there are more rows, or you're on the final page.

> i have 1568 data (buildings information) in my database

With that small number, consider caching them all in your API, and running that query over in-memory data instead of querying the database each time.

You can also just load them all on every query, and process your search logic in memory.  eg

replace

```
var query = _service.AllAsQueryable;
```

with

```
var query = _service.AllAsQueryable.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . My data increasing daily , so which way is better using elasticsearch or sql server indexing, what is limit of data row in sql server which effect to performance?

Comment: There's simple way to use indexing for that process query.  Each combination search option is a different query, would respond to different indexes.  So probably you have to scan the table for each query.  But scanning a tiny table like that should be very fast.